# Error javafx : Page language not specified

Tags: java, javafx

i make an graphic interface with JAVAFx , on NETBEANS 7.3.1 , i have a problem;  the stack trace is

```
Executing com.javafx.main.Main from C:\Users\Guillaume\Documents\NetBeansProjects4\JavaFXApplication1\dist\run1976733325\JavaFXApplication1.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java
Page language not specified.
file:/C:/Users/Guillaume/Documents/NetBeansProjects4/JavaFXApplication1/dist/run1976733325/JavaFXApplication1.jar!/javafxapplication1/Sample.fxml:30
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:510)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:594)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2472)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2177)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2069)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2830)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2809)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2795)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2782)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2771)
  at javafxapplication1.JavaFXApplication1.start(JavaFXApplication1.java:21)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:219)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:182)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:698)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:871)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Page language not specified.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:510)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:594)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2472)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2177)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2069)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2830)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2809)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2795)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2782)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2771)
    at javafxapplication1.JavaFXApplication1.start(JavaFXApplication1.java:21)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:219)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

The fxml file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="307.0" prefWidth="503.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <children>
    <Label id="lb_config" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="4.0" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="252.0" text="Configuration de compteurs SDM120" />
    <Label id="lb_select" layoutX="93.0" layoutY="70.0" text="Selection compteur adresse n°" />
    <Label id="lb_config_act" layoutX="82.0" layoutY="126.0" text="Configuration actuelle :" />
    <Label id="lb_vit" layoutX="93.0" layoutY="154.0" text="Vitesse de transmission" />
    <Label id="lb_tps" layoutX="208.0" layoutY="203.0" text="Temps" />
    <Label id="lb_imp" layoutX="134.0" layoutY="244.0" text="Sortie à impulsion" />
    <Button fx:id="bt_modif" layoutX="364.0" layoutY="273.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Modifier" />
    <TextField fx:id="tf_vit" layoutX="281.0" layoutY="154.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
    <TextField fx:id="tf_tps" layoutX="281.0" layoutY="203.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
    <TextField fx:id="tf_imp" layoutX="281.0" layoutY="241.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
    <ComboBox fx:id="me_sel" layoutX="298.0" layoutY="67.0" prefWidth="183.0" promptText="Adresse du compteur">
      <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
          <String fx:value="Item 1" />
          <String fx:value="Item 2" />
        </FXCollections>
      </items>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button fx:id="bt_visualiser" layoutX="357.0" layoutY="105.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="buttonAction" text="Visualiser" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code, instead of pasting links to it.

Answer (score 7):

You are specifying an action handler for the button for which you have no context at all:

```
<Button ... onAction="buttonAction" ... />
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#event_handler_attributes) event handlers are either specified as controller methods (the most common way), or using a scripting language (rare). To use a controller, you specify and implement a controller class, and prefix the method name that handles the event with `#`. E.g.:

```
package my.package ;

public class MyControllerClass {

    // ...

    @FXML
    private void buttonAction() {
        // code to execute when button is fired
    }
}
```

and then in FXML do:

```xml
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="307.0" prefWidth="503.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2"
    fx:controller="my.package.MyControllerClass">

    <!-- ... -->

    <Button ... onAction="#buttonAction" ... />

    <!-- ... -->
</AnchorPane>
```

If the attribute for `onAction` does not begin with `#`, it is interpreted as scripting code. This is a much less common way to handle events. For this to work, you must have a `language` directive in the FXML preamble, and the content of the `onAction` attribute must be valid scripting code:

```xml
<?language javascript?>

<!-- imports etc -->

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="307.0" prefWidth="503.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">

    <!-- ... -->

    <Button ... onAction="java.lang.System.out.println('You clicked me!');" ... />

    <!-- ... -->
</AnchorPane>
```

(And you can have `<script>` tags in which you define functions, that can be referenced from this attribute, etc. Again, see the documentation.)

In your code, because the `onAction` attribute does not start `#`, the FXML parser is expecting scripting code, but since you have no `language` directive, it cannot try to interpret it; hence the exception.

Comment: Thank you so much for mentioning the <?language javascript?> part. I was following a tutorial, hence not at the level where I went through the documentation. Spent like 3 hours hehe -_-.

Answer (score 1):

If you are providing script in fxml instead of controller, add below language tag to fxml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?language javascript?>
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#event_handler_attributes